# AJAX 2nd Request and IE6

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, internet-explorer-6

Hey.
I'm using AJAX (no Framework) to list Documents contained in Directories on the Server.
First:
The "getfiles.php" asks MySQL if the directory is password protected. If yes it returns "!pw!".
So if the responseText matches "!pw!" the second request should be triggered with the entered password and return the Documentlist.

Chrome and FireFox 3+ & 4 are doing well... but IE6 still refuses to load the List, after the password has typed in.

P.S.: Sorry for my bad English.

```
function showFiles(str)
{
var xmlhttp = false;
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari,...
       xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
       if (xmlhttp.overrideMimeType) {
           xmlhttp.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
       }

   } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
       try {
           xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
       } catch (e) {
           try {
               xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
           } catch (e) {}
       }
   }

   if (!xmlhttp) {
       alert('Unfortunately you browser doesn\'t support this feature.');
       return false;
   }    
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  switch (xmlhttp.readyState)
    {
    case 4:
        if (xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            if (xmlhttp.responseText.match("!pw!"))
                {
                var pw = prompt ("A Password is required!\nIf you don\'t have the Password, please ask your Colleagues","Passwort needed");
                xmlhttp.open("GET","getfiles.php?f="+str+"&pw="+pw,true);
                xmlhttp.send();
                }
            else
                {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            break;
    default:
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="<div align=\"center\"><img src=\"../_img/wait.gif\"/></div>";
        break;
    }

  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getfiles.php?f="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Have you used something like Fiddler and see if the Ajax call goes out. Does not work means what?

Comment: Can I ask - are you opposed to using a framework like jQuery. You will reduce your coding **substantially**, and increase cross-browser compatibility quite a bit.

Comment: Here is an untested re-write of your code using jQuery (for example). http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/6fhSJ/

Comment: I think ie6 likes you to provide `null` as an argument to `send` for `GET`  -  `xmlhttp.send(null);`

Comment: @Dutchie432: Thank you for your effort. I'm new to JS, AJAX & jQuery. I discovered jQuery just a few Days ago so i'm still playing around.  Your Code looks good, but (correct me if i'm wrong) the call of showFiles requires str AND pw correct? The pw is should not be a part of the call.... But thanks for the little bump... I will try to reconigure it for working. ;)

Comment: @Kamisama, to piggy back on what Dutchie said. You really, really should use a framework for AJAX. Not doing so leaves you open to JSON hacks, possible XSS and CRLF attacks as well as browser compatibility issues.

Comment: @Kamisama: It seemed to me that the way your code was written, you'll always get a `Password Required` message the first time the function is call since in your code `pw` is not being set until that time. You can certainly use my function and leave out the second parameter when calling the function. It should work the same way... `function showFiles("This is the str parameter")`. in the function, pw would be null and you would just need to do a check on that.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate a new XMLHttpRequest each time you start a new request instead of reusing the previous instance. That should fix it.